# Changing frame of view loaded from Xib

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, xib

I am trying to change the frame of my custom view which I load from a xib.

**Here is my init method of the view:**

```
- (id)initWithUserName:(NSString*)userName andComment:(NSString*)comment
{

    if (self) {
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Comment" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];

        self.userName = userName;
        self.comment = comment;
        NSLog(@"CREATED");
        NSLog(@"%@, %@",self.userName, self.comment);

        self.userNameButton.tag = -1;

        CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(240, 2000);
        self.userNameButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        CGSize sizeOfUsernameText = [self.userName sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:12.0] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        //color converted from #161616 Hex
        [self.userNameButton.titleLabel setTextColor:[StaticMethods colorFromHexString:@"#161616"]];
        [self.userNameButton setTitle:[self.userName stringByAppendingString:@":"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.userNameButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:12.0]];
        [self.userNameButton setNeedsDisplay];

        //[self.userNameButton addTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(userNameButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        //Append appropriate amount so that the usernames can be seen and clickable
        NSString *indentString = @" ";
        CGSize sizeOfWhitespaces = [indentString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:12.0] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        while (sizeOfWhitespaces.width < sizeOfUsernameText.width) {
            sizeOfWhitespaces = [indentString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:12.0] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            indentString = [indentString stringByAppendingString: @" "];

        }
        CGSize sizeOfComment = [comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:12.0] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        self.commentText.tag = -1;
        self.commentText.text = [indentString stringByAppendingString: self.comment];
        self.commentText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:12.0];
        [self.commentText setTextColor:[StaticMethods colorFromHexString:@"#161616"]];

    }

    return self;
}
```

**This method is called from a view controller like this:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for(int i = 0; i < self.userNames.count;i++){
        CommentView *view = [[CommentView alloc]initWithUserName:[self.userNames objectAtIndex:i] andComment:[self.comments objectAtIndex:i]];
        [view setDelegate: self];
        [self.view addSubview:view];
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0,100,320,100);


    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Now, the line where it says `view.frame = CGRectMake(0,100,320,100);` is where i try to change the views frame. **I have tried putting that code inside the view's**

`- (id)initWithUserName:(NSString*)userName andComment:(NSString*)comment`

**method body as well**, without luck.

So clearly I am having trouble resizing the view according to my preferences.
The view has always the same frame as when it is presented in interface builder.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I have tried putting the above `viewDidLoad` body inside that viewcontroller's `viewWillAppear` body, without any progress.

Comment: is autolayout enabled?

Comment: yes autolayout is enables

Comment: you have to declare -(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame; meyhod in the custom subclass named commentView

Comment: Even when the view is loaded from the nib? Do i need that method in order to set the frame ?

Comment: your  initWithMethod suggests that the view is created programmatically.How have you created it

Comment: Could you explain that a little further? I am starting to feel that you are on the right track

Comment: As you can see in the viewDidLoad method, I am allocating and creating the view

Answer (score 5):

Disabling "Use Autolayout" in .xib solved this for me.

Answer (score 3):

put your code inside

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{

}
```

it is a delegate method executes only after autolayout has executed.

Comment: Is this done in the viewcontroller or in the view? As you can see I hold no reference to the view i am adding

Comment: the code you put in `viewDidLoad` above should go in this method

Comment: It does not seem to be called.

Comment: Ok it is called, but no progress.

Comment: I can set the center of the view, not the frame however.